# How do I use JQuery to remove all "script" tags in a string of HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have a string of HTML code.  I want to use JQuery to remove all `<script>` tags from the string.

How can I do that?

Note: I want to use JQuery , not REGEX, to do this.

Does this work? `$(var).find('script').remove();`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
var stringOfHtml = // your string here
$(stringOfHtml).find('script').remove();
```

To get the new string with the script tags removed:

```
var stringOfHtml = "<div><script></script><span></span></div>";
var html = $(stringOfHtml);
html.find('script').remove();

var stringWithoutScripts = html.wrap("<div>").parent().html(); // have to wrap for html to get the outer element
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/AnjJa/1/) - Had to use p instead of script as script broke the fiddle, same principle though.

**Actual working answer here (hopefully)**

Here is a workaround for the script issue, use replace to swap the script text with something else (try and make it unique) then remove those new tags and use replace again to swap back in case script is used anywhere else in text. Yes, it does use regex, but not to remove the script tags so I'm hoping that's alright ;):

```
var stringOfHtml = "<p></p><script>alert('fail');</scr" + "ipt><span></span>";
var wrappedString = '<div>' + stringOfHtml + '</div>';
var noScript = wrappedString.replace(/script/g, "THISISNOTASCRIPTREALLY");
var html = $(noScript);
html.find('THISISNOTASCRIPTREALLY').remove();

alert(html.html().replace(/THISISNOTASCRIPTREALLY/g, 'script'));
```

[JS Fiddle Workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/AnjJa/4/)

[JS Fiddle Example With Script Text](http://jsfiddle.net/AnjJa/68/)

Comment: How do you get the resulting string?

Comment: I guess that the SO problem is that script is executed on parse it, and the `.remove()` is unuseful. [See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/tWenG/1/).

Comment: @DavidRodrigues Seems you're right. Guess this can't work on scripts but should work on any other tag.

Comment: @RichardD, what if my string of HTML doesn't have a div?

Comment: @RichardD, if you change the string to "<p></p><span></span>", it breaks

Comment: @RichardD what about manually adding the "div" to the string, and then do html.get('div').html()?

Comment: @user847495 Check my edit. It does seem to depend on there being a single wrapping element. Might be a better idea to add that yourself manually.

Comment: This answer sucks.  Your regex is going to munge any string that contains the word "script" whether that's a tag or not. -1

Comment: @g33kz0r Thanks, not sure I get what you mean though. I've added an example fiddle with the word script inside the span and it doesn't get removed.

Answer (score 13):

Old question, but if you are still looking for the easiest way to remove scripts from a string try

```
$.parseHTML(string);
```

$.parseHTML() automatically removes script tags from strings.

**Edit:**

This works because `keepScripts` has false value as default. (Reference: [$.parseHtml](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/))

```
$.parseHTML(data, context, keepScripts)
```

Comment: Works great, but how do I join the html back into a string? `parseHTML()` returns an array of DOM elements which exclude the script tags, but I'd like to join without having to insert them back into the document. I'm trying to avoid using something like $().add() or append()

Answer (score 1):

i guess this should work

```
$('script').each(function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: this is equivalent to `$('script').remove()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the other solution if one want to remove script tag from any string:

```
var str = "<script>Content...</script>"
use var afterstring = str.replace("<script>","new");
and afterstring = str.replace("<\/script>","new");
```

*Hope it will work for you !*