# How to detect window resize and then change the javascript file being added to the header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize

I have this jQuery to detect the screen size and then append a file to the header based on the sceen size.

```
var scriptSrc = '';
var widowWidth = $(window).width();
if(widowWidth >= 1024)
  scriptSrc = '/js/desktop.js';
if((widowWidth <= 1023) && (widowWidth >= 768))
  scriptSrc = '/js/tablet.js';
else if(widowWidth <= 767)
scriptSrc = '/js/mobile.js';
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = scriptSrc;
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.appendChild(script);
```

I have tried to use $(window).resize() with it but I have been unable to remove the file that was originally added before the resize is triggered.

I have a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8wC9W/) for you to change my code on and as you can see it will add the js file based on the screen size but I would like it to change if the screen does too.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I use:

```
$(window).bind('resize', function(event) {      
//Whatever you want to run here     

});
```

Just set a variable for you window width and height and check what they are at inside of this function.

As for changing your javascript file when the screen is resized with out reloading the whole page... I don't think that is possible. A work around might be to import all the javascript files into one file and just run different functions that overwrite any changes that the last javascript function made.

This obviously uses jQuery though.

Comment: this is good but same issue with how it will add the file multiple times and also not deleting the duplicates. So you think there isn't a way other than reloading the page?

Comment: You can append the html document with a new script file, but you will have to run a function on that file. So rather than messing with that, I would just have one master file that has all your other files included and just run a function. What is the end result of changing out the javascript files?

Comment: well I have some jQuery carousels that I want on desktop only, and for mobile I have some touch events that I don't want loaded on larger screens. and a few things like that.

Comment: If you just want to add and remove the javascript files from the html document, just append the src attribute of the script tags inside that function. But this will not run the new file. You would have to run the function some how. That is why I suggest using a master file. Then you just don't have to mess with changing the script src... just call a new function.

Comment: yeah I understand what you are saying, thought I would try my luck with what I have already.

Comment: Found this also [http://stackoverflow.com/a/10054132/2433381](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10054132/2433381)

Answer (score 0):

Add your code into the callback function for the resize event.

```
$(window).resize(function(elem){
    var scriptSrc = '';
    var widowWidth = $(window).width();
    if(widowWidth >= 1024)
      scriptSrc = '/js/desktop.js';
    if((widowWidth <= 1023) && (widowWidth >= 768))
      scriptSrc = '/js/tablet.js';
    else if(widowWidth <= 767)
      scriptSrc = '/js/mobile.js';
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = scriptSrc;
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.appendChild(script);
});
```

The callback function will be called when the window is resized.  However, the event will be fired for every pixel that the window changes in size, so be prepared for that

Comment: Yeah that's what I tried before and like I said I was unable to delete the one that is being loaded and only add in the new one once. is there no way to not have it do that?

Comment: you caould try using the `.remove()` method.  I found this link that could help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503560/how-do-i-use-jquery-to-remove-all-script-tags-in-a-string-of-html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to listen to the window resize event

```
var onsize = function() {
    var W = $(window).width();
    if(W >= 500) {
      test.html('/js/desktop.js');
    } else if(W >= 300) {
      test.html('/js/tablet.js');
    } else { //if(widowWidth <= 767)
      test.html('/js/mobile.js');
    }
};
```

I added a div to display the output.

$(window).resize(onsize);

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/devm33/aC8Ez/

Comment: I want it to when the page loads to load one of the js files based on the window size and then if the window is resized again after the page loads to keep checking on the size and then add in the file and delete the other accordingly