# How to escape <script> tags inside jquery html(). I used innerHTML and outerHTML to fix this but facing issues in it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add contents on loading the page and remove the contents while saving to DB.

My response has a

On load:

I got the response and try to put into test field

```
var element = document.createElement("pp");

var test = $j(element ).attr("id", "exam").addClass("exam");
        test.innerHTML = "test script <div>test</div><script src=\"test.js\" src=\"text/javascript\"></script>";
```

While accessing test[0].outerHTML i am just getting as

```
<pp class="exam" id="exam"></pp>
```

But i am expecting an output as

```
<pp class="exam" id="exam">test script <div>test</div><script src=\"test.js\" src=\"text/javascript\"></script></pp>
```

Let me know what's wrong in this

On Save:

I am getting the contents of the text field

```
 $j("#textfield").html() which has <pp class="exam" id="exam">Test<script src="test.js" src="text/javascript"></script></pp>
```

now i need to escape the

```
  <pp class="exam" id="exam"></pp>
```

so i used

```
 $j("#textfield").html().html() which is stripping the <script> tag.
```

Let me know how i can retain `<script/>` tag in this case.

Comment: "I want to add contents on loading the page and remove the contents while saving to DB."—could you explain this a little bit more? It sounds like there's probably a better solution to your problem.

Comment: While loading the contents of the page i need to put the data inside this temporary tag for visual purpose <pp class="exam" id="exam"></pp> and while save i need to strip of the temporary tag what i added.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
var stringOfHtml = // Your content HTML
$(stringOfHtml).find('script').remove();
```

[How do I use JQuery to remove all "script" tags in a string of HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503560/how-do-i-use-jquery-to-remove-all-script-tags-in-a-string-of-html)

Comment: I want to retain the script tags in the response. I updated the description

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the `<script>` tag :

```
$("<div/>").text(s).html();
```

And decode it before using it :

```
$('<div/>').html(text).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using vanilla javascript:

```
var element = document.createElement("pp");
element.id = 'exam';
element.className = 'exam';
element.innerHTML = "test script <div>test</div><script src=\"test.js\" src=\"text/javascript\"></script>";

document.body.appendChild(element);

/* Check contents of <pp id='exam'>*/
var myEl = document.querySelector('#exam').outerHTML;
console.log(myEl);
```

Output of console.log will be:

```
<pp id=\"exam\" class=\"exam\">test script <div>test</div><script src=\"test.js\"></script></pp>
```

Hope that helps!
You can read up on how innerHTML vs outerHTML works here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML